# I am getting response from query ,i want to access data in angular side seperating diffrent values in difrrent variables

Tags: json, angular

I am getting some response from API, I want to break the data and store each value in a seprate variable, using angular 
But getting the different form of data, how to call this data in angular and stored this 2 values in separate variables

```
[
    {
        "customer_info": "343136,469553"
    }
]
```

Comment: `string.split(customer_info)`?

Comment: `value[0].customer_info.split(',');`

Answer (score 0):

Use the array declaration with a secure hook :

```
const [val1, val2, ...otherValues] = firstItemOfReponse.customer_info.split(',');
```

Comment: response is an array!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, use `string.split()`

```js
var data = [{ "customer_info": "343136,469553" }]

var obj = {};

console.log(data[0].customer_info.split(','));
var splittedArray = data[0].customer_info.split(',');
for(var i=0; i < splittedArray.length; i++)
{
  obj[i] = splittedArray[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```

> EDIT:

No need of `JSON.stringify` and the call is async that why it is getting undefined:

```
this._dataService.getCustomerInfo().subscribe((result2) => {
  if (result2) {
    this.user2 = result2;
    var obj = {};
    console.log(this.user2[0].customer_info.split(','));
    var splittedArray = this.user2[0].customer_info.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < splittedArray.length; i++) {
      obj[i] = splittedArray[i];
    }
    console.log(obj); // for (let entry of this.user2) { // console.log('entry', entry); // } //console.log(data[0]) console.log("connected vs disconnected" +this.user2); // console.log("connected" +this.Connect_data); }, (error)=>{ })
  }
}
```

Comment: `how to call this data in angular and stored this 2 values in seprate variables`

Comment: core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: that mean how you are retrieving that data from API?

Comment: this._dataService.getCustomerInfo().subscribe(
(result2)=>{
  this.user2= JSON.stringify(result2);
  
var obj = {};

console.log( this.user2[0].customer_info.split(','));
var splittedArray =  this.user2[0].customer_info.split(',');
for(var i=0; i < splittedArray.length; i++)
{
  obj[i] = splittedArray[i];
}

console.log(obj);
//   for (let entry of this.user2) {
    
//     console.log('entry', entry);
// }
//console.log(data[0])
console.log("connected vs disconnected" +this.user2);
// console.log("connected" +this.Connect_data);


},
(error)=>{

})

Comment: @mridul What is result of `console.log(result2)`?

Comment: @prashant it showing [object object],thats why i have use JSON.stringify?

Comment: @mridul Try without JSON.stringify

Comment: @prashant getting same error Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: Can you give me the remote access to check?

Comment: @prashant its working van taking data as hardcode but not working with the api

Comment: @mridul what is the output of `console.log(this.user2)`

Comment: @prashant its     [{"customer_info":"343136,469553"}]

Comment: @mridul Can you give me remote access with Anydesk to check? Its something small that we are just missing

Comment: @prashant  getting same error after try edited code  of Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: Recently updated code? Or else you can share the AnyDesk Id so will take a look at the actual code

Comment: 493 728 777 any desk id

Comment: @mridul Updated the answer

Comment: @prashant thanks for your help but i am unable to get 0 index value and set it in variable

Comment: @Prashant pimpale hi need your help regarding some angular issue ,posting some variable as string into api ,but it is showing crpss origin error i have tried many approcahed but it didnt work

Comment: @mridul I am available! Share the anydesk Id

Comment: @PrashantPimpale are you avilable today?

Comment: @mridul yes but after 1 pm

Comment: @mridul is that problem is related to angular?

Comment: @yes angular and also with spring boot a minor thing ,but unable to catch that

Comment: @mridul ok give me 15 Mins

Comment: @mridul Share AnyDesk Id

Comment: 493 728 777 any desk id